# The minCompileSdk (android-30). Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30). Dependency: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0.

Comment: Either raise your `compileSdkVersion` to 31 or use an older version of that dependency.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.